# Excel JS API displayDialogAsync Error 5001

Tags: excel, office-js

I'm trying to display a dialog window from my task pane using the Excel JS API. Below is the code and my error message. Attached are screenshots of my manifest file, Add-In Code, and the error message.

```
function startAuthProcess(){

    
    try {

        devserverLog({'DialogApi Check': Office.context.requirements.isSetSupported('DialogApi', '1.1')});
        
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://localhost:3000',
        function (asyncResult) {
        
        if (asyncResult.status === 'failed') {

            devserverLog(['here is the error message!', asyncResult['error']['code'] + ": " + asyncResult['error']['message'] ]);

        } else {

            devserverLog('hit success line!');
            let dialog = asyncResult.value;
            dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, __processDialogEvent);

        }

    });

    } catch(e) {
        devserverLog({error: e.stack});
    }
```

Screenshot of Code & Manifest File
[image: screenshot of Office-JS Excel Addin code]

Comment: You never need to put the domain that's in `<SourceLocation>` into `<AppDomains>`. See [AppDomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomain). Remove that AppDomain and see if that fixes it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I rushed home and tried this. Didn't work though.

Comment: Rick - what details can I share to help pinpoint this issue?

Comment: I suggest that you install the Fiddler tool and then inspect the Request/Response when the call to `displayDialogAsync` runs. BTW, It looks like you are trying to open the same page in the Dialog that is already open in the task pane. That should work, but just as a sanity test, you might try creating a 2nd page in add-in and passing the URL to it to `displayDialogAsync`. Also, for complicated reasons, try using "1.2" instead of "1.1" in the call of `isSetSupported`.

Comment: I tried a couple different urls. I tried my main page since I figure that should work. I'm not familiar with the Fiddler tool so I will check that out. Trying the 1.2 now.

Comment: Also, for complicated reasons, try using "1.2" instead of "1.1" in the call of isSetSupported.

Comment: DialogApi Version 1.2 check FAILED! What does that mean?

Comment: Nothing. I just thought maybe there's a bug in your version of Office and it is supporting  1.2, which is still in preview, instead of 1.1. But that's not it.

Comment: - My Excel Version is 1908 (Build 11929.20638)
- I'm using ReactJs
- I'm using React Router (Hash Based routing. It looks like the IE11 browser doesn't support the html5 history api)

Comment: Rick - we are trying to use the dialog for our authentication. Are there any other resources that I can use to try and figure this out? I'm looking at the github and excel docs extensively but I'm really stuck.

Comment: You can't use the history APIs in an add-in. For information about using the dialog for auth, see the docs that begin here: [Use Dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-api-in-office-add-ins). And see also [Auth with Dialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api). I'm not familiar with React Router, but this article might be applicable: [Dialog in SPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-best-practices#best-practices-for-using-the-office-dialog-api-in-an-spa)

Comment: Thanks for sharing these. I've been reviewing those pages pretty extensively. I updated my Excel version to 2004. No change. I'm not sure what to do next?

Comment: Next I would try running the Fiddler tool and see if the Response object when `displayDialogAsync` is called has any additional error information.

Comment: I will try that. I just noticed that now my custom formulas are no longer working after the Excel update version to 2004...